# Losing session on a website between mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com

Tags: java, session, tomcat

When I login into my website checando.com.br and try to access www.checando.com.br it loses the session. When I come back to the first URL my session is restored normally. Just like if it's two different applications, but they're in the same server.

Is there any Tomcat configuration to tell it to maintain the session between www. and non-www access?

By the way I'm using Tomcat 7.0.22 and the server is Digital Ocean.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cookie has a domain in it.

Check the domain in the cookie and make sure it matches your domain.

Tomcat setting is available. sessionCookieDomain

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

You can change this programatically `ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html#setDomain(java.lang.String)

Comment: path != domain - this answer mixes them up

Comment: But how do I change this sessionCookieDomain? Can I do it programatically? Would be better.

Comment: I think you can by using `ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Eduardo Costa and dom farr. It worked and now www.checando.com.br and checando.com.br share the same domain on the cookies.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to configure Tomcat to use ".checando.com.br" as the host of the session cookie.

I never use this, but seems to be as easy as setting "sessionCookieDomain" in your context file:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html